# How to close an HttpUrlConnection after 5 minutes without getting an exception in Java?

Tags: java, http, url, network-programming, httpurlconnection

I have to open a series of urls and read some data from them. I do not want to spend more than 5 minutes for opening an url. If it takes to open too long, then I want to skip the url and move to the next url on my list. However using timeout creates an exception and in that case, I cannot continue my regular operation.

```
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)newURL(url).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
```

I tested this code and it gives me an exception after 5000 milliseconds. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: eat the exception, log it and move to next url

Comment: What does that mean? That is, once my control is in the catch block to handle the exception, how will I move on the next link? Won't my program terminate after the catch block is over?

Comment: No it won't be over. I would suggest yo to get some basic understanding of how Exceptions work in Java before moving any further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean - you can't continue your regular operation in case of a timeout?

What is wrong with:

```
for (HttpURLConnection aConnection : collectionOfConnections) {
  try {
    aConnection.setTimeout() ....
    ... probably more code
  }
  catch (WhateverExceptionWouldBeThrown) {
    ... some error handling
  }
}
```

In other words: "collect" your URLs; open them in parallel; some will work; others will cause timeouts; continue with those that could be opened.

Meaning: if you think that an exception breaks your whole program; you might want turn back to "learning" mode and read a bit more on why exceptions exist and how to deal with them; and how to make good use of them.

Comment: I mean, once my control is in the catch block to handle the exception, after the error handling, won't my program terminate? Or will it continue to run the for loop?

Comment: Your comment proves exactly what I said: you do not understand how exceptions work (because yes - if an exception is caught, and your catch block does not call System.exit, your program simply continues its flow at the point that is "following" next). As in my example - it would simply continue with that loop.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with getting an Exception. In fact that's the proper thing to do. How would you know otherwise if the connection succeeded or not?

Just handle the exception and move on (or retry).